# SQLite.net query with casted field (int to string) does not work

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I tried to query Customers from a SQLite tabel

I want those wher the Customer Number Starts with certain numbers.

The following code throws an error that sqlite does not have a methode ToString.

Can I reach my aim with Cast ?? How?

return conn.Table().Where(v => v.kdnr.ToString().StartsWith(suchtext));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using entity framework, that would probably work:

```
.Where(v=>SqlFunctions.StringConvert(v.kdnr).StartsWith(suchtext))
```

I dont know about SQLite provider

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was looking for and expected it would work! But unfortunately it is not running with sqlite.net as there is no SqlFunctions class.